# Flutter app crashes when back button is pressed

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

My app's homepage has a search bar. When the search bar is tapped, the user is redirected to the search page as follow:

```
class _HomeAppBarState extends State<HomeAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,

        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle, color: Colors.black) , onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()
        ),

        title: TextField(
          onTap: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Search()));},
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
            hintText: "Search...",
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

In the search page. The appbar has a back button and then the back button is pressed I want the user is taken back to the homepage. I tried to do by using Navigator.pop as follows:

```
class _SearchAppBarState extends State<SearchAppBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,

        leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black) , onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context)
        ),

        title: TextField(
          autofocus: true,
          //onChanged: Do Stuff here.
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
            hintText: "Search App Bar...",
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

But I got very weird results when the back button is pressed.

[image: When the back button pressed at search page.]

The screen stays like this, when I click back button once more it stays at search page.

Answer (score 4):

- try using `automaticallyImplyLeading: true,` **only on the search bar widget.** instead of providing the back button and handling the navigation stack manually.
- Remove manual or automatic Back Button from root widget.

Also, Wrap the `root` widget with [`WillPopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) :

```
build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async => false,
     child: //you root widget,
    ); 
}
```

`WillPopScope` widget will ignore any back press events to pop out the 'root' widget, Hence no issues like the ones you are having.

For more details on `WillPopScope` visit this article: 
https://codingwithjoe.com/flutter-navigation-how-to-prevent-navigation/

Regarding the problem of screen view,

If the HomePage is the parent/root widget of the app, when popping the HomeWidget it should lead to a black screen. But it seems the distorted screen view is a bug of the emulator.

Comment: It still crashes.

Comment: updated the answer Please take a look and let me know, if your problem was solved or not.

Comment: Silly mistake. I found out that I have created MaterialApp widget for each screen. I should have gave more details in the question. After removing extra MaterialApp's the back button started to work normally.

Comment: oh, okay. it's good that you found the real cause and fixed it.